# Just out of interest, what is the impact of not including a setup while mocking using Moq test framework?

Tags: moq

I just wanted to know what the impact of not including a setup during a moq unit test run. I'm only using Moq.Verify to see if my functions are called at all, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On void methods nothing will occured
2. The return value of methods will be `default(T)`
3. On partial mock(`CallBase = true`); the real implementation of the virtual method will execute
4. On strict mock; any call of non setup method will raise an exception.
5. Call `.VerifyAll()` at the end of your test will do nothing.
6. You won't be able to raise an additional actions from methods(`callback`, `raise`)

In your case it seems that you don't have to use setup method at all...

Answer (score 1):

It depends which `MockBehavior` your mock object will use.

- If it will be `Strict` and your code is trying to execute method which was not setup the test method will throw exception something like `Moq.MockException: Class.Method() invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.`.
- If it will be `Loose` then it never throws and returns default values or empty arrays, enumerables, etc. if no expectation is set for a member.